# Material-UI: Full width List inside of Grid

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Using material-ui I am trying to make a `<List />` inside of a `<Grid />` column. I want the list to scroll on overflow but also take up the width of the grid it is in. I can get both of these to work but not at the same time. the first section with the `<Grid />` is the `overflowY` functioning properly but without the full width of the `<ListItem />`:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  list: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    overflow: 'auto',
    bottom: '1em',
    top: '1em',
  },
})
...
<Grid item xs>
  <List classes={{ root: classes.list }}>
    {genereateData(35).map(item => (
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemText primary={item} />
      </ListItem>
  ))}
  </List>
</Grid>
...
<List classes={{ root: classes.root }}>
```

but if I switch the line to the last little bit of code above the full width part works. So why would the `flexGrow: 1` work in the `root` prop but not the `list` prop, and is there a way to get both? I assume it has to do with `position: absolute` but I cannot get rid of that. Just looking for a way to get both.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mzkp7vw2lx)!